# Sort NSStrings containing date

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I've got an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary has a string object for a key @"date". I need to sort the array by this date, descending. How can I do it the best way?

Comment: Quick question, does each dictionary in the array just have a single key-value pair? If so, is it possible that you could use just a single dictionary, with all the key value-pairs?

Comment: @GavinHope No, it has about 10 various elements

Comment: So the structure of the array is, array, dictionaries, ten other elements and one is the date you want to sort by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood the structure of this array, I hope this answer helped! :)

I used this method to sort an array that holds an array that held anther array that finally held a string I wanted to sort the top array by. So obviously something simple doesn't work. But i ran into this:

```
- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr;
```

In your case, i hope, this is what you'd use:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @{@"date":[NSDate date]},
                              @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*45]},
                              @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*25]},
                              @{@"date":[NSDate date]},
                              @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*5]},
                              @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*32]},
                              @{@"date":[NSDate date]},
                              @{@"date":[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60]},
                              nil];
[arrayItems sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) { //obj1 and obj2 are objects in the list of the array. so in your case a list of dictionaries, so obj1 and obj2 are dictionaries, mutable
    //And now, which is why you would use this block to sort your objects, there you'll access each date, or object, you want to have the 'power' to sort the objects inside the caller, in this case arrayItems
    NSDate *date1 = [obj1 objectForKey: @"date"];
    NSDate *date2 = [obj2 objectForKey: @"date"];

    //And now you compare the two of whom is larger
    return [date1 compare: date2];

}];
NSLog( @"%@", arrayItems);
```

I hope this helped, or hinted you to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a NSSortDescriptor, for example:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
```

This will use string comparison to compare your date strings. It should work if the date string is formatted correctly and consistently.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to format that strings into `NSDate` objects and use `compare:` method.